# Jekyll, filter if else not loading

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

the issue is that the filters syntax do not seem to work. the syntax is:

`{% if page.flip-cards.items | size > 0 %} {% include cards-scripts.html %} {% endif %}`

i think what this does is if "flip-cards" are present on the page or generated page by the cms and their items are greater than 0, then include the script for the flip-cards. i just need to load the script if the cms page has the components/templates called "flip-cards" active.

here's my approach to removing the filter and using the dot notation.

`{% if page.flip-cards.items.size > 0 %} {% include cards-scripts.html %} {% endif %}`

derived from: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#size

this one didn't work either... the script is not loading from the cms driven page using the filter and dot notation syntaxes.  can anyone help me troubleshoot? thank you in advance.

the label has the following code.

`{
label: 'Flip cards',
name: 'flip-cards',
widget: 'object',
fields: [
{
    label: 'Items',
    name: 'items',
    widget: 'list',
    fields: [
    {
        label: 'Title',
        name: 'title',
        widget: 'text',
    },
    {
        label: 'Image',
        name: 'image',
        widget: 'image',
    },
    {
        label: 'Description',
        name: 'description',
        widget: 'markdown',
    },
    {
        label: 'Reverse',
        name: 'reverse',
        widget: 'markdown',
    },
    ],
},
{
    label: 'Content',
    name: 'content',
    widget: 'markdown',
},
],
},`

Comment: What is the output of `{{ page.flip-cards.items | inspect }}` ?

Comment: Should 'items' be there?

Comment: @JoostS let me give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: @DavidJacquel will try that too

Comment: @DavidJacquel where should i position the output syntax? i tried placing it after the conditions, but i'm not sure where to check. the label has the following code attached.

Comment: `{% if page.flip-cards.items | inspect %}` did not seem to work

Comment: `| inspect` filter is used for debug. My idea is to spot if your using the right dot notation to reach desired datas. Just paste the result in your answer.

Comment: @DavidJacquel this one seems to work `{% if page.sections.flip-cards != 0 %}` basically if the page's sections which have flip-cards not equal to zero then load the script.  i might ran this to my lead developer and see if this is good.

Comment: but when i checked the other pages, the script is still loading.